# Clarity fails to install using 'ng add @clr/angular' CLI command

Tags: angular, npm

I'm following '*Chapter 3*: Building an Issue Tracking System using Reactive Forms' from *Angular Projects:* Build modern web apps by exploring Angular 12 with 10 different projects and cutting-edge technologies, 2nd Ed. by Aristeidis Bampakos.

The project in this chapter requires the installation of Clarity. According to the book (and Clarity documentation: https://clarity.design/get-started/developing/angular/), the commands to achieve this are

```
ng new foo-project
cd foo-project
ng add @clr/angular
```

Upon running these commands I get the following output

```
ℹ Using package manager: npm
⚠ Unable to find compatible package.  Using 'latest' tag.
⚠ Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.

The package @clr/angular@12.0.8 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: foo-project@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0" from @clr/angular@12.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@clr/angular
npm ERR!   @clr/angular@"12.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/foo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/foo/.npm/_logs/2021-12-29T05_20_34_198Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
```

This is the debug log

```
# npm resolution error report

2021-12-28T21:01:27.904Z

While resolving: foo-project@0.0.0
Found: @angular/common@13.1.1
node_modules/@angular/common
  @angular/common@"~13.1.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/common@"^12.0.0" from @clr/angular@12.0.8
node_modules/@clr/angular
  @clr/angular@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "@angular/common",
    "version": "13.1.1",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "foo-project",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "path": "/Users/foo/Projects/Angular/angular-projects-book/foo-project/foo-project"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/@angular/common",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "@angular/common",
        "spec": "~13.1.0",
        "from": {
          "location": "/Users/foo/Projects/Angular/angular-projects-book/foo-project/foo-project"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "@angular/common",
    "spec": "~13.1.0",
    "from": {
      "location": "/Users/foo/Projects/Angular/angular-projects-book/foo-project/foo-project"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "@angular/common",
    "spec": "^12.0.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "@clr/angular",
      "version": "12.0.8",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "foo-project",
        "version": "0.0.0",
        "path": "/Users/foo/Projects/Angular/angular-projects-book/foo-project/foo-project"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/@clr/angular",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "@clr/angular",
          "spec": "*",
          "from": {
            "location": "/Users/foo/Projects/Angular/angular-projects-book/foo-project/foo-project"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

This is the versioning info of my Angular copy

```
Angular CLI: 13.1.2
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 13.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1301.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.1.2
@angular-devkit/core            13.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.1.2
@angular/cli                    13.1.2
@schematics/angular             13.1.2
rxjs                            7.4.0
typescript                      4.5.4
```

I believe my version of Angular is not compatible with the version of Clarity fetched by npm. If so, what's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue.
As the book says that works with Angular 12, I worked with the last version of Angular 12 (**Angular 12.2.17**). 
Then I was testing with different versions of Clarity and  **Clarity 12.0.7** worked for me.

```
ng add @clr/angular@12.0.7
```

Then I don't know why but the compiler was not recognizing the UI TAGS from Clarity, and I just runned:

```
npm install @clr/ui --save
```

Then everything was running ok!

By the way, the las command I got from the official Clarity documentation: https://clarity.design/documentation/get-started

Answer (score 0):

I am using

```
 npm install @cds/core @clr/angular @clr/ui --save
```

then add to angular.json

```
"styles": [
      "node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css",
]
```

Then adding these two modules to app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ClarityModule } from '@clr/angular';
```

I used angular version 13 and version 15 it doesn't support clarity

Answer (score -1):

You can force install the required packages using npm:

```
    npm install @clr/icons @clr/angular @clr/ui @cds/core @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs  --force
```

This method does not check dependencies. Not useful in production environments but can be used in cases where a certain package is not yet updated and has not newest dependencies

Follow other instructions at: https://clarity.design/get-started/developing/angular/

The other options is to downgrade to Angular version 12. This allows installing the clarity package without warning.